# Google Analytics tracking not recognized in flask app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, google-analytics, flask

I added the piece of javascript Google Analytics gives you to the  of my template, but Analytics says tracking is not installed. I've used Analytics on several static pages before without any issue. Are there complexities of my setup that are keeping tracking from working?

Here's the template/repo
https://github.com/mlincoln/wikieditprof/blob/beta/templates/base.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('create', 'UA-7728530-11', 'heroku.com');
```

does not seem to a valid API call according to the [Google Analytics analytics.js reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create).

You could use either :

```
ga('create', 'UA-7728530-11');
```

or if what you want is to set the cookie domain to heroku.com :

```
ga('create', 'UA-7728530-11', {'cookieDomain': 'heroku.com'});
```

Comment: It's odd that the js straight from Analytics is not in that format. Regardless, I tried getting rid of the 'heroku.com' part and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by using ga.js instead of analytics.js